# Same let binding leads to different compilation results

Tags: ocaml

```
type 'a tree =
    | Leaf of 'a
    | Node of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree 

let rec foldtree init op = function
    | Leaf c -> op c init init
    | Node (c, l, r) -> op c (foldtree init op l) (foldtree init op r)

let size' = foldtree 0 (fun _ l r -> 1 + l + r)  (* this compiles fine *)
let size'' = foldtree 0 (fun _ l r -> 1 + l + r) (* this doesn't *)
```

In the above OCaml code, the definitions of `size'` and `size''` are identical yet the latter causes a compilation error:

```
Error: The type of this expression, '_weak1 tree -> int,
       contains type variables that cannot be generalized
```

Answer (score 0):

They should both fail to compile, as both contain weak type variables. The compiler will only report one fatal error at a time, however.

Incidentally, you would usually fix this problem by eta-expansion:

```
let size tree = foldtree 0 (fun _ l r -> 1 + l + r) tree
```